# Data is not getting inserted inside the Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have created a database in Firebase and the rules set for it are:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

The format of the database is like:

```
fieldglass-aeca7
   0
    age: 23
    name:"shikher"
   1 
    age: 24
    name:"samarth"
```

Now I want to add another record to it with age:12 and name: xyz

I have written a code in the Oncreate() function as follows:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 ..............

FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
        DatabaseReference fg=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("fieldglass-aeca7");

        User u=new User(12,"shikhermishra");

        String key=fg.push().getKey();
        fg.child(key).setValue(u);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        fg.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Log.d("listener", "the data has changed");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

My user class is:

```
public class User {

public int age;
 public String name;

 public User(){
 }
 public User(int age,String name)
 {
  this.name=name;
  this.age=age;
 }

}
```

But my values are not getting inserted into the database.And there is no error reported in the Log as well.I have used all the functions which were mentioned in https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write 
link of firebase provided. How can I insert the data into my database?

Comment: While I don't see the actual problem with the setValue call, note that `Thread.sleep()` is malicious and unnecessary; and you should use the `Task` returned by `setValue` to check if it's complete instead of a single value event listener.

Comment: As @vzsg says: remove the sleep. It is not needed and just pollutes the code. Then [attach an error listener to the `setValue()` call](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase/5548/how-do-i-listen-for-errors-when-accessing-the-database/19721/detect-errors-when-writing-a-value-on-android#t=201611102318156472506) and check if it indeed fails.